# How to pass class instances to react children without breaking updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a react-redux app what is the best practice for passing collections of action creators to child components?

To be more specific I want to have a class that performs network requests for me. I want to make different instances of that class for different endpoints. The methods in that class are action creators. How do I pass a specific instance of that class to my subcomponents without breaking redux connect shallow comparison? Do I have to implement custom shouldComponentUpdate methods? Is there a whole better way of doing this?

Comment: passing it as a `props`?

Comment: I should have made clear that yes I am passing the instance as props but I am thinking that redux connect will only check shallowly so passing class instance will probably break that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually components divided for better maintainability : [HOC(container) and presentatianal components..](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.s75zquy70)

**if your container includes presentational components:**

You don't need to pass your actions creators through presentations components, because they shouldn't have any knowledge of redux parts.
If presentational component fires some action , **you should use callbacks to invoke dispatch in container**.

**for using different instances of action creator class**

first way

```
import ActionsClass from './Actions/ActionsClass';
const actions = ActionsClass('endpoint');

class Container extends Component {...}
export default connect(state=>({foo:state.foo}),actions)(Container);
```

second dynamic way, passing endpoint through props

```
import ActionsClass from './Actions/ActionsClass';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

class Container extends Component {...}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps)=>({
   actions: bindActionCreators(ActionsClass(ownProps.endpoint) , dispatch) 
});

export default connect(state=>({foo:state.foo}),mapDispatchToProps)(Container);
```

i guess, you may use [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) for `ActionsClass(ownProps.endpoint)`

third dynamic way without Class, passing endpoint to action

```
import actions from './actions';

class Container extends Component {
    onChange(arg1,arg2){
       this.props.someAction(arg1,arg2,this.props.endpoint)
    }
    render(){
       return(<SomeComp onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
    }
}

export default connect(state=>({foo:state.foo}),actions)(Container);
```

btw, also you can pass endpoint from store `state=>({endpoint:state.endpoint})`

fourth... get endpoint from action creators, through [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

```
const actionFetch = (notes) => (dispatch,getState)=>{
    let endpoint = getState()[notes].endpoint;
    fetch(endpoint).then(...
    //or let endpoint = endpointsFromModule[notes].fetchAll;
}
```

Comment: thank you for a nice collection of possibilities. I also thought of some of them but wasn't sure if they would cause troubles down the road.